# how to get info about the user and the processes he is running in systemd?

Tags: users, systemd, processes

If I wanted to know who is logged in since when and what are the processes currently running under his control, how can I do that in systemd?

Comment: See [this wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) for a start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need systemd for that … but there's a systemd way of doing it *as well*, as long as you are running the `systemd-logind` daemon, or something that provides the same API.

First obtain a list of sessions:

```
$ systemd-loginctl list-sessions
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            
       c89       1000 jdebp            seat0           

1 sessions listed.
```

Then for each session that you are interested in show its status:

```
$ systemd-loginctl session-status c89
c89 - jdebp (1000)
       Since: Tue, 07 Oct 2014 20:16:20 +0100; 15s ago
      Leader: 24453 (3)
        Seat: seat0; vc6
         TTY: /dev/tty6
     Service: login; type tty; class user
      Active: yes
      CGroup: /user/jdebp/c89
          ├ 24453 login
          ├ 25661 -zsh
          └ 25866 systemd-loginctl session-status c89
```

The systemd people have renamed them to `loginctl` and `logind` in more recent versions.

### Further reading

- [`loginctl`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html).  freedesktop.org.
- [`logind` API](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/).  freedesktop.org.
- [GSOC 2014: systemd replacement utilities (systembsd)](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20140915064856&mode=flat).  *OpenBSD Journal*.  2014-09-12.

Comment: Also: ```ps --no-header -eo user:32,slice,cmd|awk '$2 != "-" && ! _[$0] { _[$0]++; print }'``` If you're interested in kernel threads running as root, you can remove the ```$2 != "-" &&``` part

Answer (score 2):

You don't need systemd for that.

> I wanted to know who is logged in since when

Use `who`

```
$ who
jimmij   tty7         2014-09-25 01:39 (:0)
jimmij   pts/0        2014-09-25 01:39 (:0)
jimmij   pts/2        2014-09-28 22:14 (:0)
```

or even better `w` to get additional information

```
$ w
jimmij   tty7      25Sep14 12days  4:09m  5:24  sawfish
jimmij   pts/0     25Sep14 53:43   8.81s 32:32  /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python-exec/python2.7/ter
jimmij   pts/2     28Sep14  8days 45.08s  2.45s /bin/zsh
```

> What are the processes currently running under his control

use `ps -u user`

```
$ ps -u jimmij
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  352 ?        00:00:01 systemd
  353 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
  359 ?        00:05:24 sawfish
  372 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch
  373 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
  375 ?        00:00:16 sawfishpager
  377 ?        00:32:32 terminator
  ...
```