# How do I setup user autostart and properly configure systemd user services?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, users, systemd-unit

On my arch server, I was setting up users restricted to their home directories. I ran:

`useradd -m -s /bin/bash username` and `passwd username`

I've read [this wiki article...](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User)

I figured I should use systemd user services to make each user run a node server on startup. So i logged into one user account `su username` and created a file `~/.config/systemd/user/serve.service` containing:

```
[Unit]
Description=One of the servers

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/username/server.js

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

then I ran `systemctl --user enable serve.service` which responded with `Failed to connect to bus: Permission denied`

As far as I understand I should run `systemctl --user ...` command logged in as a user and not as root.

So what did I miss in this configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So I logged into one user account `su username`

No, you did not.

*You are not logging in.*  You are augmenting the privileges of *your existing login session* with `su username`.

`systemctl` with the `--user` option locates your per-user Desktop Bus, managed by you per-user Desktop Bus dæmon, and via that bus communicates with your per-user instance of `systemd` that manages your per-user servics.

*`su` is not a login mechanism*.  It works *within an existing* interactive login session.  In that session, your processes have environment variables that tell them where your per-user runtime directory is (`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`), where the per-user Desktop Bus is (`DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`), and indeed other things like where your X server is (`DISPLAY`).

In particular, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` can implicitly reference `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` or can explicitly name the same path.  That path will generally be something like `/run/user/1001/bus` for the Desktop Bus broker's access socket (presuming that your user ID is 1001, for example).

These variables are not changed by `su`.  There's been a whole back and forth for many years over this, including the behaviours of other similar commands such as `pkexec`.

The consequence of this is that if you `su` to a second user in your login session, running `systemctl` as that second user tries to connect to a Desktop Bus broker access socket located in a directory private to the first user.  User 1002 (to pick a user ID for your second user for the sake of example) cannot access `/run/user/1001` or anything within it, and even if xe had read+execute access to that directory xe cannot access `/run/user/1001/bus` because that only grants access to user 1001 also.

Of course, this is *not* the right Desktop Bus broker to be talking to in the first place.  You want to talk to the *second* user's Desktop Bus broker, and through it to the second user's per-user instance of `systemd`.

The simple solution is as part of the `su` to set those environment variables to the ones appropriate for the second user account, pointing to the second user's Desktop Bus:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1002/bus su username -c 'systemctl --user'
```

I of course in such circumstances use a handy tool for setting this, `userenv`, which enables me not to have to type that bus address longhand:

```
su username -c 'userenv --set-dbus systemctl --user'
```

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407863/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423648/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). *[Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard.  [`userenv`](https://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/guide/userenv.html).  nosh toolset manual pages.  Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427917/5132