# unable to create directory '/run/user/7093511/dconf': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly

Tags: permissions, rhel, dconf

I'm getting following error message running an aplication:

(process:53978): dconf-CRITICAL **: 12:30:48.383: unable to create directory '/run/user/7093511/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

The problem is that I have permissions to write in /run/user/7093511 (700) so I'm really confused where that comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You use selinux?
Similar problem :
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1795044

Comment: No, selinux is disabled on the server.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434494/how-do-i-setup-user-autostart-and-properly-configure-systemd-user-services

Comment: Not quite the problem - I'm not impersonating any user via su - that message is displayed when I run a process myself. And I have permissions to create files in that directory.